# caption for \starttables

Tags: tables, captions, context

How can I put caption for a `\starttables`? I am using context to generate a pdf with captions on top of tables, which are to be auto-numbered.

I have tried `\placetable`, but without any success. Also, I am limited to using only `\starttables`.

```
\placetable{Validation Migration (TAF-69)}
\starttablehead
\HL
\NC Req. Id
\NC Description
\NC Test Scenario
\NC Result
\NC\AR
\HL
\stoptablehead
\starttabletail
\HL
\stoptabletail
\starttables
\NC TAF-89

\NC Trigger test start - from jig

\NC 
\NC Unavailable

\NC\AR
\NC TAF-88

\NC Trigger test start - using scanner

\NC 
\NC Unavailable

\NC\AR
\stoptables
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax in ConTeXt is

```
\placefloat[<place>][<reference>]{<caption>}{<float body>}
```

[image: output]

```
\setupbodyfont[plr,11pt]
\enableregime[utf]

\starttext
\placetable{Validation Migration (TAF-69)}{%
  \starttablehead
  \HL
    \NC Req. Id \NC Description \NC Test Scenario \NC Result
  \AR
  \HL
  \stoptablehead
  \starttables[|l|l|l|l|]
  \AR
    \NC TAF-89 \NC Trigger test start - from jig \NC \NC Unavailable\MR
    \NC TAF-88 \NC Trigger test start - using scanner \NC \NC Unavailable\MR
  \stoptables
  }
\stoptext
```